# Sequences in which, one value of $K$ work for all $ε$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

We say a sequence $(x_n)$ of real numbers converges to $x\in\mathbb{R}$ "if $\forall\epsilon>0$ $\exists$ $K\in\mathbb{N}$ such that, $|x_n-x|<\epsilon$ for all $n≥K$"

**My question** : Are there any non constant sequences where unique value of $K$ works for all value of $\epsilon$? Is there any special name given to such sequences?

Comment: The sequence has this property iff $x_n = const$ for all $n \ge K$.

Comment: "Ultimately constant" is the term I would use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x_1=0$ and $x_n = 1$ for $n \ne 1$. Clearly $(x_n) \to 1$ and choosing $K = 2$ we have $ |x_n - 1 | < \epsilon $ whenever $n \geq K$

If $K$ is fixed then the sequence $(x_n)$ must have finite number of distinct terms. To see this suppose for all $ \epsilon > 0$ a unique $K$ works, let $n$ be fixed number then $|x_n - x | < \epsilon $ for all $ \epsilon > 0$. We claim that $x_n = x$ for all $n \geq K$ , otherwise there would be fixed $ \epsilon$ below which the equality doesn't hold which certainly not possible since choosing $ \epsilon /2$ instead of $ \epsilon$ will be a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$$|x_n-x|<\epsilon\enspace\forall\epsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}\implies x_n=x$$